# java: interface to get lines from a File or String?

Tags: java, file, iterator

I have a method that iterates over the lines of a file. At present it does the whole dance of opening the file and closing it.

Now I want to change the method, so that I can pass in an instance of some interface, possibly `Iterator<String>`, so that I can *either* read from a file, *or* just get the lines from a `List<String>` if I want to provide the input directly.

Is there a convenient way to do this? Writing my own method of deriving an `Iterator<String>` from a `File` seems like it would be very tricky to get correct.

I guess the closest way I can think of is to use Guava's [Files.readLines()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), but that's not an iterator, so it has problems with very large files.

Comment: Can you elaborate why LineProcessor not being Iterator would be a problem to read large files? Even if you had an iterator, it would still not allow skipping some content without reading it. Whilst with LineProcessor you can always return false to stop processing which is basically the same thing. It's the same thing, just with reversed control.

Comment: Right, the inversion of control is kind of a pain in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own interface and two lightweight classes that implement it, one that encapsulates `Iterator<String>` and one that takes its input from a File:

LineReader2.java:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

public interface LineReader2 extends Closeable 
{
    void close() throws IOException;
    String readLine() throws IOException; 
}
```

LineReaders2.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LineReaders2 
{
    private LineReaders2() {}

    static class FileLineReader implements LineReader2 
    {
        final private BufferedReader br;

        public FileLineReader(Reader in)
        {
            this.br = new BufferedReader(in);
        }
        @Override public void close() throws IOException {
            this.br.close();
        }
        @Override public String readLine() throws IOException {
            return this.br.readLine();
        }       
    }

    static class StringIteratorReader implements LineReader2
    {
        final private Iterator<String> it;

        public StringIteratorReader(Iterator<String> it) {
            this.it = it;
        }
        @Override public void close() {}
        @Override public String readLine() {
            return this.it.hasNext() ? this.it.next() : null;
        }       
    }

    static public LineReader2 createReader(File f) throws IOException
    {
        return new FileLineReader(new FileReader(f));
    }
    static public LineReader2 createReader(Iterable<String> iterable)
    {
        return new StringIteratorReader(iterable.iterator());
    }
    static public LineReader2 createReader(Iterator<String> iterator)
    {
        return new StringIteratorReader(iterator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

java.io.Scanner implements Iterator, so I think that's exactly what you want. Write your method to expect an Iterator, and then you could pass a Scanner opened on a file, or an Iterator from a list of Strings.

Comment: Huh. Just read the javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html -- Looks like I could do that if I set the delimiter to the end-of-line characters.

Comment: ARGH -- Why the @#$#@$ doesn't `Scanner` implement `Closeable`? It has a close() method.

Comment: I know this sounds bad, but you can consider extending Scanner and writing a finalizer which does .close(). Just don't tell anybody I suggested this :) By the way, Scanner implements AutoCloseable in Java 7.

Comment: oh good, so they've fixed it. I was trying to file a bug but Oracle's site hung when I tried logging in. >:-(

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't strike me as too difficult to write an `Iterator` implementation that simply wraps a `BufferedReader` (around a `FileReader` or similar).

As is common with self-rolled iterator implementations, you might need to do single-element look-ahead in order to implement `hasNext()` properly, but asides from that wrinkle you can more or less just delegate to `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

In fact, it wouldn't surprise me to learn that there's already a third-party class that does this (though I'm not aware of one at present).

Comment: Hmmm... there's gotchas here. See Guava issue 405: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=405

Comment: @Jason S: true, but that's essentially unavoidable.  There's always a possibility of `IOException` when doing file IO, so *if* you want the lines to be read lazily *and* they're coming from a file, any invocation of `hasNext()`/`next()` could fail with an IO error.  The Iterator interface doesn't give you a clean way to recover here, but unless you've cached the whole file beforehand, all possible implementations will face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) has a [`LineIterator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html) class. From the Javadoc:

> The recommended usage pattern is:
>
> ```
> LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
> try {
>   while (it.hasNext()) {
>     String line = it.nextLine();
>     // do something with line
>   }
> } finally {
>   it.close();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
interface ISourceOfLines
{
       List<String> getLines();
}

public class FileSource : ISourceOfLines
{
      public FileSource(String filename)
      {
          // store fileName
      }

      public List<String> getLines()
      {
         // open file and return lines
      }
}
```